# jQuery Validation Plugin - prevent repeating error messages

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a rule that says for each Stage the total quantity selected must equal the number of passengers on a booking.  Each Stage is defined in a DIV like in this example:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="Stage_1">
    <select data-stage="1" id="Quantity1" name="Items[1].Quantity">...</select>
    <select data-stage="1" id="Quantity2" name="Items[2].Quantity">...</select>
    <select data-stage="1" id="Quantity3" name="Items[3].Quantity">...</select>
</div>
<div id="Stage_2">
    <select data-stage="2" id="Quantity4" name="Items[4].Quantity">...</select>
    <select data-stage="2" id="Quantity5" name="Items[5].Quantity">...</select>
</div>
```

So for example if I have a booking with 4 passengers in the above sample the sum value of Quantities 1-3 must equal 4 and also the sum value of the Quantities 4-5 must also equal 4.

I then use the jQuery validation plugin to validate...

**Script**

```
function ValidateStages(value, element, options) {
    var stage = options[0];

    var valid = true;
    var arrVS = new Array(0);

    jQuery('div[id*="Stage_' + stage + '"] select[id*="Quantity"]').each(function () {
        var e = jQuery(this);
        if (arrVS[e.attr('data-stage')] == undefined) {
            arrVS[e.attr('data-stage')] = 0;
        }
        arrVS[e.attr('data-stage')] += parseInt(e.val());
    });

    for (key in arrVS) {
        if(arrVS[key] != MaxPassengers) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    return valid;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("validate_stages", ValidateStages, "Stage {0} error ");

    jQuery('form:first').validate({
        errorContainer: "#ValidationSummary",
        errorLabelContainer: "#ValidationSummary",
        rules: {
            "Items[1].Quantity": { validate_stages: [1] } ,
            "Items[2].Quantity": { validate_stages: [1] } ,
            "Items[3].Quantity": { validate_stages: [1] } ,
            "Items[4].Quantity": { validate_stages: [2] } ,
            "Items[5].Quantity": { validate_stages: [2] } 
        },
    });
});
```

**Questions**

I have the following issues:-

1. The error message is displayed for each dropdown on the page.  So for example if says "*stage 1 error stage 1 error stage 1 error stage 2 error stage 2 error*".  If Stage 1 and Stage 2 are invalid it should just display "*stage 1 error stage 2 error*"
2. As you can see the rules are hard coded.  I did try to create a function (see below) that creates the rules on the fly but I don't know how to apply it.  If I try and do *rules: { GetRules() }* then I just get an error saying "expected :"

   ```
   var GetRules = function () {
       var rules = '';
       jQuery('div[id*="Stage_"]').each(function (i) {
           jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ' select[id*="Quantity_"]').each(function (j) {
               var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
               rules = rules + '"' + name + '": { validate_stages: [' + (i + 1) + '] }, ';
           });
       });

       if (rules.length > 2) {
           rules = rules.slice(0, -2);
       }
       return rules;
   }
   ```

Comment: I've figured out how to dynamically create the rules, I just now need to find out how to only display the error message once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.  I needed to group the controls on the validator.  Once this was done I was able to display each stages error in a separate container.  The groups and rules are created dynamically as shown below...

```
var validation =
{
    errorContainer: "#ValidationSummary",
    errorLabelContainer: "#ValidationSummary",
    groups: {}, rules: {}, messages: {}
};

jQuery('div[id*="Stage_"]').each(function (i) {
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ' select[id*="Quantity_"]').each(function (j) {
        var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
        var Rule = name;
        validation.rules[Rule] = { validate_stages: [i + 1] };
    });
});

jQuery('div[id*="Stage_"]').each(function (i) {
    var group_ctrls = ''
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ' select[id*="Quantity_"]').each(function (j) {
        var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
        group_ctrls = group_ctrls + name + ' ';
    });
    validation.groups['group_' + i] = group_ctrls;
});

jQuery('form:first').validate(validation);
```